# keras.models.load_model throws 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model created as follows:

```
max_len = 80

def input_mask(input):
  mask = np.ones(13)
  mask[12] = 0
  mask = mask[None,:]
  mask = keras.layers.Dot((1,2))([mask, input])
  mask = keras.layers.Flatten()(mask)
  return mask

def make_conv_model():
  input = keras.layers.Input((max_len, 13))
  l = keras.layers.Flatten()(input)
  def conv_block(inp, kern, res):
    shaped = keras.layers.Reshape((1,128))(inp)
    c = keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=(kern,), padding='same', activation='relu')(shaped)
    c = keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(c)
    f = keras.layers.Flatten()(c)
    ff = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(f)
    ad = keras.layers.Multiply()([ff, res])
    return ad
  first = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(l)
  l = first
  for i in range(10):
    l = conv_block(l, 4*(i+1), first)
  l = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(l)
  l = keras.layers.Dense(max_len, activation='sigmoid')(l)
  l = keras.layers.Multiply()([input_mask(input), l])
  return keras.Model(input, l)
model = make_conv_model()
opt = keras.optimizers.adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

Which I then save:

```
model.save('./conv_model')
```

Loading the model like this:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('./conv_model')
```

Leads to the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py in int_shape(x)
   1468   """
   1469   try:
-> 1470     shape = x.shape
   1471     if not isinstance(shape, tuple):
   1472       shape = tuple(shape.as_list())

AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "dot_5" (type Dot).

'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=[[['tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)']], 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 80, 13), dtype=float32)']
```

I am unable to understand what is causing this error. Is there some special treatment required to save the numpy constant "mask" used in input_mask?